# how do l will set setOAuthToken in google picker api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

What should l will be passing to setOAuthToken in

addView(view).
             addView(uploadView).
             setAppId("2845265023234663")
             .setOAuthToken('???')
            .setCallback(pickerCallback).

As the token session l am getting contains a string in json form containing access_token, id_token etc. please help me what l will be using and setting DocsUploadView.setIncludeFolders(true) is not showing me the folders while uploading and nor this DocsUploadView.setParent(string) function is working please help me if anybody has the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `access token` from authorization response. If you don't have one, then don't call it. That is fine, but the user will have to authenticate.

Comment: but it is now working with id_token and when l use access_token it rejects the upload